# Create Custom Tage for html using php

Tags: php, html, regex

is it possible to create custom tag using php like i am trying to do

```
$str="[code] Code will goes here [/code]"
echo preg_replace("<div style='background-color:yellow;padding:5px'>$1</div>","/\[code\](.+)\[\/code\]/i",$str);
```

so the [code] will be the custom tag for me

Comment: Your expression and replacement strings are passed to `preg_replace()` in the wrong order, `\[\\code\]` in the expression should read `\[\/code\]`, and you should use a non-greedy quantifier `(.+?)`, and you should probably use `preg_replace_callback()` so you can `htmlspecialchars()` the matched code string... but apart from that it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close:

```
$str = "[code] Code will goes here [/code]";

//Pattern, Replacement, Original String

echo preg_replace(
    "/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/",
    '<div style="background-color:yellow;padding:5px">$1</div>',
    $str
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is eventually possible.

What you are looking in fact is a bbcode parser, am I right ?

If that the case, check out: [StringParser_BBCode](http://www.christian-seiler.de/projekte/php/bbcode/doc/en/chapter1.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$str = "[code] Code goes here, and it can safely contain <html> tags [/code]";
echo preg_replace_callback(
  '#\[code\](.+?)\[/code\]#i',
  function($matches) {
    return "<div style='background-color:yellow;padding:5px'>".htmlspecialchars(trim($matches[1]))."</div>";
  },
  $str
);
```

...or for PHP < 5.3:

```
function bbcode_code_tag($matches) {
  return "<div style='background-color:yellow;padding:5px'>".htmlspecialchars(trim($matches[1]))."</div>";
}

$str = "[code] Code goes here, and it can safely contain <html> tags [/code]";
echo preg_replace_callback('#\[code\](.+?)\[/code\]#i', 'bbcode_code_tag', $str);
```